# How to pass DDK makefile variable to MS-DOS batch

Tags: batch-file, makefile, dos, wdk

In DDK makefile, there is predefined macro/variable $(O), whose value is sth like objchk_win7_x86\i386.

In MS-DOS batch, it calls 'build' into this makefile. and next I would like to use the variable $(O) to specify the output dir.

so is it possible to pass the maro $(O) to MS-DOS batch as a variable?

thanks for any hints.

the ms-dos batch may look like:

```
set ddk=c:\winddk\7600.16385.1
cd    /d %my_libs%
build /zwg  // Call DDK makefile. The makefile defines macro $O=xxx.

set out_dir=%O%  // How to use the makefile marco/variable here ..
cp /y %out_dir% c:/
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the DDK make process but with most other processes if you set an environment variable with the parameter then it will be defaulted in the build.

For example

```
set O=%out_dir%
```

Unless I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Passing an environment variable to the build should have no issue, my question is the opposite, i.e., how to export the makefile macro to MS-DOS command environment? In GNU makefile, the rules are "targets : prerequisites recipe", where we can execute system command to export variable to env in recipe. I didn't see similar rules to execute custom recipe in DDK makefile/source. thanks for your comments anyway.

Comment: one idea I have is have the build generate a batch file while compiling (echo set O=%out_dir% > setvars.bat) then execute the bat file once the build is done and the settings will be available as environment variables.  Unfortunately the makefile runs in a seperate environment and you can't pass back the env settings specifically without cheating like this.